# Raspberry Pi 3 VLAN interface DHCP client issue

Tags: pi-3, networking, raspberry-pi-os, dhcp

I have followed the guideline to setup VLAN interface on eth0 but failed to auto get IP address from my upstream dhcp server. I have checked tcpdump and don't see any dhcp traffic on VLAN interfaces. Is there any missing in my configuration?

1. `apt-get install vlan`
2. `echo "8021q" >> /etc/modules & modprobe 8021q`
3. Setup vlan interface

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/vlans
auto eth0.20
iface eth0.20 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0

auto eth0.23
iface eth0.23 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0

auto eth0.24
iface eth0.24 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0
```

4. Restart networking service `systemctl restart networking`

Comment: "I have followed the guideline" - what guideline? This uses Debian networking which is not used & incompatible with Raspberry Pi OS `dhcpcd`

Comment: @Milliways Are you sure about the incompability? I tested it on `Raspberry OS 2022-09-22` and it creates a vlan interface and start dhcpd to retrieve a IP address.

Comment: @MatsK attempts to use Debian networking while dhcpcd is running creates contention (although it can be done if properly configured) but the OP has provided no evidence. Your answer is a kludge which "works" because it causes dhcpcd to disable itself when it invokes DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `inet manual` to `inet dhcp` so the VLAN subinterfaces gets a DHCP address.

`inet manual` Does not define an IP address for an interface

`inet dhcp` Get a DHCP IP address for the interface

And do the upstream offer DHCP on the VLANs 20, 23 and 24 ?

**PS.** Please post the `tcpdump` command for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. It works. May I know how to change default eth0 up but without any IP address? I have looked at "https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#A3_ways_to_configure_the_network" -Bringing up an interface without an IP address, but not sure which file should be edited.

Comment: I dont understand what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: In Pi I have eth0, eth0.20, eth0.23 and eth0.24 and I just want to enable eth0 interface without getting any IP, may be just change the eth0 to "manual" but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Just add to your `/etc/network/interfaces.d/vlans`  file  `auto eth0` and `iface eth0 inet manual` If I understand you right. And please mark my answer as an answer to your question.